# Python, ImportError: MaxentClassifier

Tags: error-handling, python-2.7, nltk

I am readying the book Natural Language Processing with Python.

http://rafale.org/~mattoufoutu/ebooks/Doc_diverse/Cours%20Prog/Python/Books/Natural%20Language%20Processing%20with%20Python%20%282009%29.pdf

Paragraph 7.5   Named Entity Recognition.

I follow the example and write:

```
sent = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents()[22]
print nltk.ne_chunk(sent, binary=True)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/__init__.py", line 176, in ne_chunk
    chunker = load(chunker_pickle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 605, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/named_entity.py", line 16, in <module>
    from nltk.classify import MaxentClassifier
ImportError: cannot import name MaxentClassifier
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Thanks!

EDIT: content of the file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/**init**.pyc

```
from nltk.classify.api import ClassifierI, MultiClassifierI
from nltk.classify.mallet import config_mallet, call_mallet
from nltk.classify.megam import config_megam, call_megam
from nltk.classify.weka import WekaClassifier, config_weka
from nltk.classify.naivebayes import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.classify.positivenaivebayes import PositiveNaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.classify.decisiontree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from nltk.classify.rte_classify import rte_classifier, rte_features, RTEFeatureExtractor
from nltk.classify.util import accuracy, apply_features, log_likelihood

# Conditional imports

try:
    from scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
except ImportError:
    pass

try:
    import numpy
    from nltk.classify.maxent import (MaxentClassifier, BinaryMaxentFeatureEncoding,
                                      TypedMaxentFeatureEncoding,
                                      ConditionalExponentialClassifier)
    import svmlight
    from nltk.classify.svm import SvmClassifier
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: could you do `import nltk.classify` and `print nltk.classify.__file__`. as well as showing the content of the folder of that file?

Comment: from nltk.classify.api import ClassifierI, MultiClassifierI
from nltk.classify.mallet import config_mallet, call_mallet
from nltk.classify.megam import config_megam, call_megam
from nltk.classify.weka import WekaClassifier, config_weka
from nltk.classify.naivebayes import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.classify.positivenaivebayes import PositiveNaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.classify.decisiontree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from nltk.classify.rte_classify import rte_classifier, rte_features, RTEFeatureExtractor
from nltk.classify.util import accuracy, apply_features, log_likelihood

Comment: try:
    from scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
except ImportError:
    pass

try:
    import numpy
    from nltk.classify.maxent import (MaxentClassifier, BinaryMaxentFeatureEncoding,
                                      TypedMaxentFeatureEncoding,
                                      ConditionalExponentialClassifier)
    import svmlight
    from nltk.classify.svm import SvmClassifier
except ImportError:
    pass

Comment: If you add this to your question and use the `{}` Button then I can read it :)

Comment: The file is found at: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/__init__.pyc

Comment: yep, I didn't think I could add it...

Comment: Thanks! Do you have numpy installed? `from nltk.classify.maxent import (MaxentClassifier,...` is behind `import numpy` you should install numpy. and be able to do `import numpy` without error.

Comment: Yeah, indeed! In fact, I am having problems to install numpy, for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: I have been following the instruction here: http://nltk.org/install.html, but that does not help. I'll open another thread. Thanks for helping me with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have **numpy** installed:

```
from nltk.classify.maxent import (MaxentClassifier,...
```

is behind

```
import numpy
```

you should install numpy and be able to do import numpy without error.

Comment: This is handled here: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/368#issuecomment-18462653

Answer (score 0):

In the file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/named_entity.py
change

```
from nltk.classify import MaxentClassifier
```

to

```
from nltk.classify.maxent import MaxentClassifier
```